# irb keeps saving history, even though turned off via IRB configuration

Tags: ruby, jruby

I have in my .irbrc the statements

```
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = nil
IRB.conf[:EVAL_HISTORY] = nil
```

but irb still creates a history file. Do I need to set something else?

**UPDATE**: On request, this is the effective command used to run `irb` (pathes shortened):

```
export IRBRC=/path/to/irbrc_for_testing.rb
java -Xmx4G -cp /path/to/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.27/jruby-complete-1.7.27.jar org.jruby.Main /path/to/bin/jirb_swing_ex
```

The files jruby-complete-1.7.27.jar and jirb_swing_ex were downloaded from the JRuby web site.

The file `irbrc_for_testing.rb` contains the IRB.conf settings.

Comment: Adding those statement to `~/.irbrc` worked for me with Ruby 3.1.2p20. What version are you using?

Comment: @Max: Pretty exotic: _jruby 1.7.27 (1.9.3p551)_ . Perhaps this configuration was not yet implemented in this old version.

Comment: I tried to run the same command the same way. I'm not sure what `jirb_swing_ex` is but I used `jirb_swing` from jruby-dist-1.7.27-bin.tar.gz. Otherwise I ran it the same way. For me, it won't save history at all _until_ I create a config file that tells it to save history. So I'm very confused why you are seeing the opposite behavior.

Comment: @Max : `jirb_swing_ex` is, as I found out, a slightly customized version of `jirb_swing`. Your comment made me look in a new direction, and in the end made me find how to solve my problem. I posted an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

My irb setup file (i.e. the one which configures `IRB.conf`) performs at the end the command `load(user_irbrc)`, where the variable `user_irbrc` (by some unfortunate circumstances) pointed to a certain irbrc setup file put in place by the `rbenv` version manager (which I used some times ago for switching between MRI rubies). It seems that this rbenv irbrc was responsible for putting back `IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY]` to the value of 100.

After I fixed that undesired `load` command, history saving is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the [jruby source code for your release](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/1.7.27/lib/ruby/1.9/irb/init.rb#L56) that those config values are used even in that version of irb. The issue must simply be in how it is trying to load your config file.

You can see lower down in that same file that irb also looks for an environment variable to locate the config. Try running it like this

```
IRBRC=/path/to/your/irbrc irb
```

Comment: Perhaps it is a henn-and-egg problem? I do have set `IRBRC` to load my custom rc file, and INSIDE this file I change the IRB.conf. Isn't this the way it is supposed to be done?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And, again, I have tested setting up my config in this way and it works.

Comment: Perhaps my invocation of itb itself is faulty: I am running it basically as `java /path/to/jruby-complete-1.7.24.jar org.jruby.Main /path/to/jirb_swing_ex`. Is the `irb` you are using a shell script, which handles the irb invocation?

Comment: @user1934428 please update your original question to include all of the following information: what version of ruby are you using and how was it installed/built, what is the exact command you are using to invoke irb? where is your config file located?

Comment: Information added!

Answer (score 0):

By default, `irb` will store the last 1000 commands you used in `IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE]` (~/.irb_history by default).

If you want to disable the history feature, add `IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = nil` to your .irbrc file and run the `irb` command in the same directory where your .irbrc file is located.

Comment: As you see from my posting, this is exactly the setting I have.